# Vueify not working with ES2015 - Gulp

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify, vue.js

I'm stuck on trying to get browserify/vueify to output ES2015 with Gulp. I did what [the documentation](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify) said which is:

> npm install\
>     babel-core\
>     babel-preset-es2015\
>     babel-runtime\
>     babel-plugin-transform-runtime\
>     --save-dev

And I have this in my gulpfile:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    browserify('./js/entry.js')
    .transform(vueify)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./js/bundle.js'))
});
```

The documentation states:

> Support ES2015 by default.

Am I suppose to require or import all the npm modules in my gulpfile or something? What am I missing here? Browserify works fine but as soon as I use ES2015 gulp errors out on me with:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (32:6) while parsing...
```

Comment: Vueify supports es2015 inside Vue files, but I think you also need to pipe through browserify with es2015 enabled if you use it in `entry.js`

Comment: @Jeff I figured out that it is indeed only enabled for .vue files. Guess I overlooked it. Maybe create an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vueify supports es2015 inside Vue files, but you also need to pipe through browserify with es2015 enabled if you use it in `entry.js`.  Browserify handles `.js` files and it needs to know es2015 too `:)`

Comment: Do you mean "pipe through *babelify*" ?